# How to use lint4j plugin for gradle build and how to configure it for Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, lint

The following plugin configuration is for maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>lint4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jutils-lint4j-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  <type>plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Then I can add the following snippet to the of the reports section of my project.xml

```
<report>jutils-lint4j-plugin</report>
```

Add the following line to the project's maven.properties file:

```
maven.repo.remote=http://www.ibiblio.org/maven,http://www.jutils.com/maven
```

But I want the same thing for gradle. Apart from the required build.gradle change, Do I need anything else to be changed in the project so as to see lint report in Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 0):

Other then ensuring you have the [gradle plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) installed and configured:

```
<hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle plugin="gradle@1.24">
        <description/>
        <switches> -Dtest.single=com/mycomp/test/trusted/**/*Tests
            -Dtest.scaleDefaultWaits=2.0</switches>
        <tasks>clean test</tasks>
        <rootBuildScriptDir/>
        <buildFile/>
        <gradleName>gradle-1.12</gradleName>
        <useWrapper>false</useWrapper>
        <makeExecutable>false</makeExecutable>
        <fromRootBuildScriptDir>true</fromRootBuildScriptDir>
        <useWorkspaceAsHome>false</useWorkspaceAsHome>
    </hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle>
```

I did find this online that might serve as a guide for you: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Gradle-Projects-with-Jenkins-CI#create-the-build-job

Comment: Appreciated your help. But actually I know how to configure a gradle project in Jenkins, and I am successfully building my project. I just wanted to know how to install lint4j plugin while building a gradle project in Jenkins. It has to do something with modification in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following piece of code to build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories { jcenter() }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:latest.release'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.lint'

gradleLint.rules = ['dependency-parentheses', 'dependency-tuple']
```

Add your custom rules, and ignore cases.